# Add class to previous Item in ng-repeat in Directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

Here is an example of re-usable progress-bar which uses ng-repeat and directive.

[**Plunker**](http://plnkr.co/edit/rehu5YTB97w1nbxOMG5b?p=preview)

As i have class .progressBar__isActive foe the current page or index value. I want to add progressBar__isComplete class to all the previous list item. 
In Code i have

```
 data-my-progress-bar data-currentPage="0" data-currentPageStyle="progressBar__isActive
```

Which will add class to the current index item. But suppose i have data-currentPage="2". I would like to add  progressBar__isComplete class to the last two list items.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

replace the content of ng-class with:

```
ng-class="{ {{cssActivePage}}: $index == indexActivePage, progressBar__isComplete : $index < indexActivePage}"
```

That works, but you probably want to make it more similar to {{cssActivePage}}

Answer (score 0):

Try this. You need to use `<=` instead of `=`.

**HTML**

```
<div data-my-progress-bar data-currentPage="2" data-currentPageStyle="progressBar__isActive" data-pages="['Step 1','Step 2','Step 3','Step 4']">
  </div>
```

**HTML ProgressBar**

```
<li ng-repeat="page in allPages" ng-class="{ 'progressBar__isActive': $index == indexActivePage,'progressBar__isComplete' : $index < indexActivePage}">
        {{page}}
      </li>
```

[Updated Code](http://plnkr.co/edit/UHwg29LI7MrSUyzn0djc?p=preview)

Comment: I don't want to add same class name to previous list items.

Comment: As suggested by Walter, you can add number of diff classes in ng-class but you need to wrap it in single or double quote to make it work.

Comment: @JayShukla I see it working without quotes as well. But strictly speaking you're probably right